# Active Directory: Get all group members

Tags: c#, sql-server, active-directory, ldap, ldap-query

Question: How do I retrieve all group members in a consistent manner?

Context: I am retrieving all objects that are either person, group, contact, or computer:

```
Filter = "(|(objectCategory=person)(objectCategory=computer)(objectCategory=group))"
```

I now need to retrieve all members of groups. I have developed three methods to do this; however, they are returning different results for the same group and I am not sure why. I suspect that it may be caused by nested groups (i.e., groups within groups). Debugging it is a challenge because some groups contain so many members that the debugger times out and shows no results.

Method 1 and 2 is slow. Method 3 is fast. So, I prefer to use method 3.

```
Group Name      Retrieval Method    Recursive Search    Count Members   Comment
Group1          AccountManagement   TRUE                505 
Group1          AccountManagement   FALSE               505 
Group1          DirectoryServices   N/A                 101 
Group2          AccountManagement   TRUE                440             Contains group name 'Group3'
Group2          AccountManagement   FALSE               440             Contains group name 'Group3'
Group2          DirectoryServices   N/A                 100             Contains group name 'Group3'
Group3          AccountManagement   TRUE                101             All Group3
Group3          AccountManagement   FALSE               2               All Group3
Group3          DirectoryServices   N/A                 2               1 user 1 group (Group2)
```

**Method 1 and 2**: Get group members using the `S.DS.AM`, where the GetMembers() is set to either true or false, respectively: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement(v=vs.110).aspx

```
private static List<Guid> GetGroupMemberList(string strPropertyValue, string strDomainController, bool bolRecursive)
        {
            List<Guid> listGroupMemberGuid = null;
            GroupPrincipal groupPrincipal = null;
            PrincipalSearchResult<Principal> listPrincipalSearchResult = null;
            List<Principal> listPrincipalNoNull = null;
            PrincipalContext principalContext = null;
            ContextType contextType;
            IdentityType identityType;

            try
            {
                listGroupMemberGuid = new List<Guid>();
                contextType = ContextType.Domain;
                principalContext = new PrincipalContext(contextType, strDomainController);
                identityType = IdentityType.Guid;

                groupPrincipal = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(principalContext, identityType, strPropertyValue);

                if (groupPrincipal != null)
                {
                    listPrincipalSearchResult = groupPrincipal.GetMembers(bolRecursive);
                    listPrincipalNoNull = listPrincipalSearchResult.Where(item => item.Name != null).ToList();
                    foreach (Principal principal in listPrincipalNoNull)
                    {
                        listGroupMemberGuid.Add((Guid)principal.Guid);
                    }
                }
                return listGroupMemberGuid;
            }
            catch (MultipleMatchesException)
            {
                throw new MultipleMatchesException(strPropertyValue);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
            finally
            {
                listGroupMemberGuid = null;
                listPrincipalSearchResult.Dispose();
                principalContext.Dispose();
                groupPrincipal.Dispose();
            }
        }
```

**Method 3**: Get group members using the `S.DS.AD`: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.activedirectory(v=vs.110).aspx

```
private static List<string> GetGroupMemberList(string strPropertyValue, string strActiveDirectoryHost, int intActiveDirectoryPageSize)
        {
            List<string> listGroupMemberDn = new List<string>();
            string strPath = strActiveDirectoryHost + "/<GUID=" + strPropertyValue + ">";
            DirectoryEntry directoryEntryGroup;
            DirectoryEntry directoryEntryGroupMembers;
            DirectorySearcher directorySearcher;
            SearchResultCollection searchResultCollection;
            DataTypeConverter objConverter = null;

            objConverter = new DataTypeConverter();

            try
            {
                directoryEntryGroup = new DirectoryEntry(strPath, null, null, AuthenticationTypes.Secure);
                directoryEntryGroup.RefreshCache();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }

            try
            {
                directorySearcher = new DirectorySearcher(directoryEntryGroup)
                {
                    //Filter = "(objectCategory=group)", // Group
                    SearchScope = SearchScope.Subtree,
                    PageSize = intActiveDirectoryPageSize,
                };
                directorySearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("objectGUID");
                searchResultCollection = directorySearcher.FindAll();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }

            try
            {
                foreach (SearchResult searchResult in searchResultCollection)
                {
                    directoryEntryGroupMembers = searchResult.GetDirectoryEntry();

                    foreach (object objGroupMember in directoryEntryGroupMembers.Properties["member"])
                    {
                        listGroupMemberDn.Add((string)objGroupMember);
                    }
                }
                return listGroupMemberDn;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
            finally
            {
                listGroupMemberDn = null;
                strPath = null;
                directoryEntryGroup.Dispose();
                directoryEntryGroupMembers = null;
                directorySearcher.Dispose();
                searchResultCollection.Dispose();
                objConverter = null;
            }
        }
```

**Method 4**: (Loop with GetNextChunk() method implementation)

```
 private static List<string> GetGroupMemberList(string strPropertyValue, string strActiveDirectoryHost, int intActiveDirectoryPageSize)
    {
        // Variable declaration(s).
        List<string> listGroupMemberDn = new List<string>();
        string strPath = strActiveDirectoryHost + "/<GUID=" + strPropertyValue + ">";
        string strMemberPropertyRange = null;
        DirectoryEntry directoryEntryGroup = null;
        DirectorySearcher directorySearcher = null;
        SearchResultCollection searchResultCollection = null;
        // https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms676302(v=vs.85).aspx
        const int intIncrement = 1500;

        // Load the DirectoryEntry.
        try
        {
            // Setup a secure connection with Active Directory (AD) using Kerberos by setting the directoryEntry with AuthenticationTypes.Secure.
            directoryEntryGroup = new DirectoryEntry(strPath, null, null, AuthenticationTypes.Secure);

            // Load the property values for this DirectoryEntry object into the property cache.
            directoryEntryGroup.RefreshCache();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        { }

        #region Method1
        // Enumerate group members.
        try
        {
            // Check to see if the group has any members.
            if (directoryEntryGroup.Properties["member"].Count > 0)
            {
                int intStart = 0;
                while (true)
                {
                    // End of the range.
                    int intEnd = intStart + intIncrement - 1;

                    strMemberPropertyRange = string.Format("member;range={0}-{1}", intStart, intEnd);

                    directorySearcher = new DirectorySearcher(directoryEntryGroup)
                    {
                        // Set the Filter criteria that is used to constrain the search within AD.
                        Filter = "(|(objectCategory=person)(objectCategory=computer)(objectCategory=group))", // User, Contact, Group, Computer objects

                        // Set the SearchScope for how the AD tree is searched (Default = Subtree).
                        SearchScope = SearchScope.Base,

                        // The PageSize value should be set equal to the PageSize that is set by the AD administrator (Default = 0).
                        PageSize = intActiveDirectoryPageSize,

                        PropertiesToLoad = { strMemberPropertyRange }
                    };

                    try
                    {
                        // Populate the searchResultCollection with all records within AD that match the Filter criteria.
                        searchResultCollection = directorySearcher.FindAll();

                        foreach (SearchResult searchResult in searchResultCollection)
                        {
                            var membersProperties = searchResult.Properties;

                            var membersPropertyNames = membersProperties.PropertyNames.OfType<string>().Where(n => n.StartsWith("member;"));

                            foreach (var propertyName in membersPropertyNames)
                            {
                                // Get all members from the ranged result.
                                var members = membersProperties[propertyName];

                                foreach (string memberDn in members)
                                {
                                    // Add the member's "distinguishedName" attribute value to the list.
                                    listGroupMemberDn.Add(memberDn);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    catch (DirectoryServicesCOMException)
                    {
                        // When the start of the range exceeds the number of available results, an exception is thrown and we exit the loop.
                        break;
                    }

                    // Increment for the next range.
                    intStart += intIncrement;
                }
            }

            // return the listGroupMemberDn;
            return listGroupMemberDn;
        }
        #endregion

        finally
        {
            // Cleanup objects.
            listGroupMemberDn = null;
            strPath = null;
            strMemberPropertyRange = null;
            directoryEntryGroup.Dispose();
            directorySearcher.Dispose();
            searchResultCollection.Dispose();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement` can be more convenient, since it hides much of the complexity of AD, but that is also what makes it slower. You have less control over what's going on.

`DirectoryEntry` gives you more control, but you have to handle some of the complexity.

So that can explain the time difference.

But your method that uses `DirectoryEntry` still seems overly complicated. Why use `DirectorySearcher`? It doesn't seem to add anything. You already have the group when you set `directoryEntryGroup`. After that, you can access the members:

```
foreach (var member in directoryEntryGroup.Properties["member"]) {
    //member is a string of the distinguishedName
}
```

For very large groups, be aware that by default AD limits the records it returns to 1500. So once you hit that number, you will have to ask for more. You do that like this:

```
directoryEntryGroup.RefreshCache("member;range=1500-*")
```

Then loop through them again the same way. If you get exactly another 1500, then ask for more (replacing the 1500 with 3000), etc. until you have them all.

This is exactly what the .NET Core implementation of `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement` does (and I presume the .NET 4.x does too - I just can't see that code). You can see the special class .NET Core code uses to do this here (see the `GetNextChunk` method): https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/0eb5e7451028e9374b8bb03972aa945c128193e1/src/System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement/src/System/DirectoryServices/AccountManagement/AD/RangeRetriever.cs

As a side note:

```
catch (Exception ex)
{
    // Something went wrong. Throw an error.
    throw ex;
}
```

If you are going to re-throw an exception without doing anything else, just don't catch it. Re-throwing has the effect of hiding where the exception actually happened, because your stack trace will now say that the exception happened at `throw ex;`, rather than tell you the actual line where the exception happened.

Even for your last block, you can use `try`/`finally` without `catch`.

Comment: Thank you for the code clean-up recommendations. However, do you have any idea why I would be getting different counts?

Comment: I can't really say. `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement` actually uses `DirectoryEntry` in behind, so the numbers should be the same. The only numbers that should be different are the recursive lookups. How many members are there actually in each group?

Comment: That is a good question - I am trying to figure that out. I have actually tried building a SQL hierarchy to see if I can get IsDescendants() of the groups in order to see if that would be helpful - but I am getting stuck there too. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49022116/active-directory-convert-canonicalname-node-value-from-string-to-integer

Comment: Also, if I set the first the catch block black, then subsequent try/catch blocks will show a compile error regarding the use of unassigned variables, which were assigned in the previous try block (that now has a blank catch block). Any recommendations on how to get around this?

Comment: I usually just initialize them as `null` when I declare them, if I can't combine the declaration with the assignment (like `var listGroupMemberGuid = new List<Guid>();`)

Comment: For very large groups you can run into paging problems (where you have to ask for more) but that limit is 1500 by default. I updated my answer with that information. But with the numbers you are showing, that shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: That worked. I was unaware of the 1,500 limit as I had not yet come upon it during my research efforts as I pursued other routes. I would like to point out that from an optimization standpoint, looping through via an implementation of GetNextChunk() is significantly faster than using the S.DS.AM wrapper's GetMembers() function by two orders of magnitude! For example, a group with ~6,500 members completed in 1,097 milliseconds using the loop versus 205,642 milliseconds for GetMembers(). Thank you sir, I tip my hat to you.

Comment: Awesome! Yeah, I've tried using `AccountManagement` namespace, but I keep coming back to `DirectoryEntry`. It gives you more control of what's going on.

Comment: I have been attempting to do some code clean-up, but I do not see how to rationalize the implementation of the GetNextChunk() method with your comment to just use directoryEntryGroup.RefreshCache("member;range=1500-*"). Can you please show how?

Comment: The `1500` needs to change depending on how many records you already have. So it should be a variable, like `$"member;range={count}-*"` where `count` is however many records you already have. You keep doing that until you get less than 1500 results, then you know you have them all.

Comment: I'm sorry to be a pest, but can you actually provide an answer as to how the method should be coded as opposed to code snippets?