# Flatten hierarchical sql output

Tags: sql-server

How to go about flattening hierarchical data to columns for the following use case

```
Current: EmployeeID, ManagerID


Transformed: EmployeeID, ManagerID, ManagersManagerID...
```

Employees with no manager will have NULL for Manager ID

Employees with big manager hierarchy will have that many columns with NULL for the last column. For e.g employee with level 4 hierarchy will have following columns

```
EmployeeID, ManagerID, Level2ManagerID,  Level3ManagerID, Level4ManagerID, Level5ManagerID
```

Here Level5ManagerID will be NULL

Comment: Do you have any code written already?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option is to use a standard recursive cte to build the hierarchy with a PATH, and then parse the path with a little XML

This assumes you know the max level

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable Table ([ManagerID] varchar(50),[EmployeeID] varchar(50))
Insert Into @YourTable Values 
 (null ,'S-1')
,('S-1','S-11')
,('S-1','S-12')
,('S-1','S-13')
,('S-1','S-14')
,('S-1','S-15')
,('S-11','S-111')
,('S-11','S-112')

;with cteP as (
      Select EmployeeID
            ,ManagerID 
            ,PathID = cast(EmployeeID as varchar(max))
      From   @YourTable
      Where  ManagerID is Null
      Union  All
      Select EmployeeID  = r.EmployeeID
            ,ManagerID  = r.ManagerID 
            ,PathID = cast(p.PathID+','+cast(r.EmployeeID as varchar(25)) as varchar(max))
      From   @YourTable r
      Join   cteP p on r.ManagerID  = p.EmployeeID)
Select [EmpID] = EmployeeID
      ,B.*
 From  cteP A
 Cross Apply (
                Select Level1 = xDim.value('/x[1]','varchar(max)')
                      ,Level2 = xDim.value('/x[2]','varchar(max)')
                      ,Level3 = xDim.value('/x[3]','varchar(max)')
                      ,Level4 = xDim.value('/x[4]','varchar(max)')
                      ,Level5 = xDim.value('/x[5]','varchar(max)')
                From  (Select Cast('<x>' + replace(PathID,',','</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml) as xDim) as X 
             ) B

  Order By PathID
```

**Returns**

```
EmpID   Level1  Level2  Level3  Level4  Level5
S-1     S-1     NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
S-11    S-1     S-11    NULL    NULL    NULL
S-111   S-1     S-11    S-111   NULL    NULL
S-112   S-1     S-11    S-112   NULL    NULL
S-12    S-1     S-12    NULL    NULL    NULL
S-13    S-1     S-13    NULL    NULL    NULL
S-14    S-1     S-14    NULL    NULL    NULL
S-15    S-1     S-15    NULL    NULL    NULL
```

Comment: @JohnCappelleti I have posted a similar question regarding hierarchies. You seem well versed on the subject. Kindly, can you please take a look and let me know if you can think of any solutions? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49022116/active-directory-convert-canonicalname-node-value-from-string-to-integer

Comment: @JWeezy I'll take a peek