# SQL query to get list of all records that are placed higher in hierarchy

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql

**Table:**

```
+-----+------------+-------------+
| Id  | DocumentNo | ParentCCID  |
+-----+------------+-------------+
|  10 | CC001      | NULL        |
|  20 | CC002      | CC001       |
|  33 | CC003      | CC002       |
+-----+-------------+-------------+
```

Value passed to the query: `CC003`

**Expected Output:**

```
CC003
CC002
CC001
```

**Failed Attempt:**

```
select b2.documentno,b2.ParentCCID  from basicdetails  b1 
inner join basicdetails b2 on b1.documentno = b2.ParentCCID 
where b2.documentno='CC003'
```

Note: DocumentNo is unique primary key. ParentCCID could have null values if there is no parent record.

**EDIT:**

```
create table basicdetails2
  (
    id int identity,
    documentno varchar(30),
    parentccid varchar(30)
  )
    insert into basicdetails2 values('CC001', null)
    insert into basicdetails2 values('CC002', 'CC001')
    insert into basicdetails2 values('CC003', 'CC002')
    insert into basicdetails2 values('CC004', 'CC003')
```

Comment: Why does the attempt fail?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a minor twist on Gordon's answer (already +1).

I like to track the level and see the parents for each record

**Example**

```
Declare @Fetch varchar(25) = 'CC003'

;with cte as (
      Select DocumentNo
            ,ParentCCDocumentNo
            ,Lvl=1
      From   YourTable 
      Where  DocumentNo=@Fetch
      Union  All
      Select R.DocumentNo
            ,R.ParentCCDocumentNo
            ,P.Lvl+1
      From   YourTable R
      Join   cte P on P.ParentCCDocumentNo = R.DocumentNo)
Select Lvl = Row_Number() over (Order By Lvl Desc)
      ,DocumentNo
      ,ParentCCDocumentNo
From cte
Order By 1 desc
```

**Returns**

```
Lvl DocumentNo  ParentCCDocumentNo
3   CC003       CC002
2   CC002       CC001
1   CC001       NULL
```

Comment: So that worked, but I wonder if there is a non-recursive solution?

Comment: @SamuraiJack Technically yes, but they can get a little ugly, especially if you have a variable depth hierarchy..   Are you looking for more than one path at a time?

Comment: Depth can vary but there only be a single immediate parent to a record

Comment: @SamuraiJack Since your have a variable or jagged hierarchy, then a Recursive CTE is by far the best option.  Just another option for your consideration  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49695115/flatten-hierarchical-sql-output/49695556#49695556

Answer (score 1):

You want a recursive cte:

```
with cte as (
      select bd.documentno, bd.ParentCCID
      from basicdetails bd
      where bd.documentno = 'CC003'
      union all
      select cte.documentno, cte.ParentCCID
      from cte join
           basicdetails bd
           on bd.documentno = cte.ParentCCID
     )
select bd.documentno
from cte;
```

Comment: @SamuraiJack Methinks the `join` should be `on bd.documentno = cte.ParentCCID`. And the second `select` should be `bd.documentno, bd.ParentCCID`, not `cte.`.