# How to create a hierarchy table out of a list of strings representing a location?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, common-table-expression, hierarchy

I have a table of strings, where each string represents a Geo-location and each level is separated by a "|".
The entries does not always have the same number of levels and the same entry may exist multiple times. I expect ca. 10000 strings with ca. 200 unique location information. Format looks like this sample data:

```
"Germany|Berlin|Hauptstrasse|123"
"France|Paris|CDG-Chausee"
"Germany|Munich|Bavariaplatz|234"
"Germany|Munich|Ludwigsallee"
"France|Paris|CDG-Chausee"
...(ca. 10000 more entries)
```

Now I need to convert this into a table representing a hierarchy (unbalanced tree) to be able to answer the following questions:

a) Which nodes are direct childen of a given node?

```
e.g. "Munich"  -> Bavariaplatz, Ludwigsallee
e.g. "Germany" -> Berlin, Munich
```

b) How many (which) nodes in total do I have in the tree below a given node?

```
e.g. "Munich"  -> 3 (Bavariaplatz, Ludwigsallee, 234)
e.g. "Germany" -> 7 (Berlin, Munich, Hauptstrasse, Bavariaplatz, Ludwigsallee, 123, 234)
```

I have no experince with the type "HierarchyId" in MS SQL, if this can help for the given problem,
but I know that I could get the answers of the above questions with a table structure like this:

```
id; name;    level; parentId; sortPath
 1; France;       1; NULL; "France"
 2; Paris;        2;    1; "France|Paris"
 3; CDG-Chausee;  3;    2; "France|Paris|CDG-Chausee"
 4; Germany;      1; NULL; "Germany" 
 5; Berlin;       2;    4; "Germany|Berlin"
 6; Hauptstrasse; 3;    5; "Germany|Berlin|Hauptstrasse"
 7; 123;          4;    6; "Germany|Berlin|Hauptstrasse|123"
 8; Munich;       2;    4; "Germany|Munich"
 9; Bavariaplatz; 3;    8; "Germany|Munich|Bavariaplatz" 
10; 234;          4;    9; "Germany|Munich|Bavariaplatz|234"
11; Ludwigsallee; 3;    8; "Germany|Munich|Ludwigsallee"
```

I was trying with a recursice CTE and also with Transact SQL, but with no luck.

My idea is, to sort all strings first and then get the first part (country) till first "|" and create an entry in a result table (or for next CTE iteration) for any new country and skip it, if its still the same than the one before to avoid duplicates. Also remember the position of the "|" we just processed and add a column for the iteration representing the hierarchy-level. Then in the next iteration get the full string-part till the second "|" character, from here get the part after the last "|" (city) and assign it as a child to the already created country. If the next entry start with same "country|city|" part then skip it. Repeat this iteration till we have no more "|" levels left in any string.

Or can this all be skipped by using the HierarchyId type? E.g. replacing the "|" with a dot and then we have it?

Can someone help, please?

Comment: In order to display the direct children of a given node, you need to give the node. `'Paris'` isn't a node since it could be in `'France'`, `'Iowa'`, `'Maine'`, ... . How do you plan to identify a node for that purpose? By `Id`? [This](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49022116/92546) question and answer may be of interest.

Comment: If Paris can appear multiple times, of course. That depends on the input table.

Answer (score 1):

The following code demonstrates how to pull apart the pipe (`'|'`) delimited locations using the modern edition of [`string_split`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) which supports returning an `ordinal` for each `value` so that the order of the elements can be preserved. The results are then recombined one level of depth (aka *generation* with respect to parents and children) at a time to build the `hierachyid` values for each location.

Some examples of querying the results for locations within Munich via the `hierarchyid` values and methods are included.

A [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/euEpyacw) is provided for testing.

```
-- Sample data.
declare @Locations as Table ( LocationId Int Identity, Location NVarChar(256) );
insert into @Locations ( Location ) values
  ( N'Germany|Berlin|Hauptstrasse|123' ),
  ( N'France|Paris|CDG-Chausee' ),
  ( N'Germany|Munich|Bavariaplatz|234' ),
  ( N'Germany|Munich|Ludwigsallee' ),
  ( N'France|Paris|CDG-Chausee' );
select LocationId, Location, Len( Location ) - Len( Replace( Location, '|', '' ) ) as Depth
  from @Locations;

-- Demonstrate how to start pulling things apart.
--   This code is not used to generate the result, it's just here for educational value.
declare @LocationElements as Table ( LocationElementId Int Identity, Location NVarChar(256), LocationElement NVarChar(256), Depth Int );
insert into @LocationElements ( Location, LocationElement, Depth )
  select L.Location, LE.LocationElement, LE.Depth
    from @Locations as L cross apply
      ( select value as LocationElement, ordinal - 1 as Depth from String_Split( L.Location, '|', 1 ) ) as LE;
select * from @LocationElements;

-- Get the distinct paths that we need to build the hierarchy, one generation at a time.
declare @Hierarchy as Table ( LocationElementId Int Identity, LocationElement NVarChar(256), LocationPath NVarChar(256), Depth Int, HI HierarchyId );
declare @Depth as Int = 0, @RowCount as Int = 1;
while @RowCount > 0
  begin
  insert into @Hierarchy ( LocationElement, LocationPath, Depth, HI )
    select distinct LE.LocationElement, Coalesce( H.LocationPath + '|', '' ) + LE.LocationElement, LE.Depth, null
      from @LocationElements as LE left outer join
        @Hierarchy as H on H.Depth = LE.Depth - 1 and LE.Location like H.LocationPath + '%'
      where LE.Depth = @Depth;
  select @RowCount = @@RowCount, @Depth += 1;
--  select @Depth - 1 as D, * from @Hierarchy; -- Uncomment this statement to see the action one generation at a time.
  end;
select * from @Hierarchy;

-- Connect the children to the parents, one generation at a time.
select @Depth = 0, @RowCount = 1;
while @RowCount > 0
  begin
  update HC
    -- The hierarchy id is the parent's hierarchy id with the child's identity appended.
    set HI = Cast( Coalesce( Cast( HP.HI as VarChar(256) ), '/' ) + Cast( HC.LocationElementId as VarChar(6) ) + '/' as HierarchyId )
    from @Hierarchy as HC left outer join
      @Hierarchy as HP on HP.Depth = @Depth - 1 and HC.LocationPath like HP.LocationPath + '|%'
    where HC.Depth = @Depth;
  select @RowCount = @@RowCount, @Depth += 1;
--  select @Depth - 1 as D, * from @Hierarchy; -- Uncomment this statement to see the action one generation at a time.
  end; 
select * from @Hierarchy;

-- Query the result.
declare @MunichId as HierarchyId = ( select HI from @Hierarchy where LocationElement = 'Munich' );  -- NB: Assuming it is singular.
select @MunichId as MunichId;
-- All children of Munich:
select * from @Hierarchy
  where HI.IsDescendantOf( @MunichId ) = 1 and HI.GetLevel() = @MunichId.GetLevel() + 1;
-- All descendants of Munich:
select * from @Hierarchy
  where HI.IsDescendantOf( @MunichId ) = 1;
```

There's probably a more elegant way to beat this into submission with `Row_Number()` and `curse apply` *[sic]*, but it wasn't cooperating with me as the night wears on.

Comment: Wow! Many thanks for this. Now I just need to replace string_split with a couple of old-fashioned string-manipulations, because the server does not have the required compatibility-level for string_split.

Comment: @Carsten FWIW, I've used a string splitter based on [Jeff Moden's](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/tally-oh-an-improved-sql-8k-%E2%80%9Ccsv-splitter%E2%80%9D-function) work for quite some time.

Comment: How do I use that in a CTE or in TSQL? I cannot setup a function in the current context.

Comment: @Carsten There isn't a trivial way to sneak the string splitting functionality into the existing queries if you aren't allowed to use [`create function`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-function-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) to create a table-valued function. Can a DBA add the function for you if you provide the source code?

Answer (score 0):

you do not need to represent the level you can use this hierarchy

Create table with these culomns Id,Name,Parent (Nullable)

the perant is null when no perant there
and to get the chilern for some nodes with Id this is the query

```
WITH RECURSIVE HierarchicalCTE AS (
    SELECT Id, Name, Parent, 1 AS Level
    FROM HierarchyTable
    WHERE Id = :parent_id
    
    UNION ALL
    
    SELECT ht.Id, ht.Name, ht.Parent, hcte.Level + 1 AS Level
    FROM HierarchyTable ht
    JOIN HierarchicalCTE hcte ON ht.Parent = hcte.Id
    WHERE hcte.Level < 3  -- Specify the desired level here
)
SELECT Id, Name, Level
FROM HierarchicalCTE;
```

Comment: But I dont have this columns in the input table.

Comment: the level info is needed later to answer the question like "how many nodes do I have in the tree below Germany?"